# Example of making screenshot using Foreground MediaProjection Button

Tags: kotlin, screenshot, foreground-service, android-mediaprojection

I try to realize an application which is include a creation of screenshot using Foreground MediaProjection Button OUTSIDE of any activity.
Unfortunatelly, information provided in official page of MediaProjection APi https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/media-projection is not enough for understanding what exactly I should to do.
Please, provide some guide with sample code on this topic or reference link.
[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/bubbles

Comment: Did you get any solution after that?